# how to set spring annotation bean in custom spring xml schema parser?

Tags: spring, annotations, schema

I write a spring xml schema like this

```
<route:urls id="urlHandlerMap">
    <route:url pattern="user/api/**" beforeHandlers="defaultBeforeHandler"/>
</route:urls>
```

this is my schema parser

```
public class ApiRouteParser extends AbstractSingleBeanDefinitionParser {
    private static String DEFAULT_BEFORE_HANDLER = "defaultBeforeHandler";

    private static String ROUTE_URL_FIELD = "route:url";
    private static String PATTERN_FIELD = "pattern";
    private static String BEFORE_HANDLER_FIELD = "beforeHandlers";

    @Override
    protected Class getBeanClass(Element element) {
        return UrlHandlerMap.class;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doParse(Element element,ParserContext parserContext, BeanDefinitionBuilder builder) {
        NodeList urlList = element.getElementsByTagName(ROUTE_URL_FIELD);
        ManagedMap<String, BeanMetadataElement> urlHandlerMapperDefinition = new ManagedMap<String, BeanMetadataElement>();
        for (int i=0; i < urlList.getLength(); i++){
            Element urlNode = (Element)urlList.item(i);

            String pattern = urlNode.getAttribute(PATTERN_FIELD);
            String beforeHandlers = urlNode.getAttribute(BEFORE_HANDLER_FIELD);

            if (StringUtils.isEmpty(beforeHandlers)){
                beforeHandlers = DEFAULT_BEFORE_HANDLER;
            }


            BeanDefinitionBuilder urlHandlerBuilder = BeanDefinitionBuilder.genericBeanDefinition(UrlHandler.class);

            urlHandlerBuilder.addPropertyValue("beforeHandlerList", parseList(beforeHandlers));
            urlHandlerMapperDefinition.put(pattern, urlHandlerBuilder.getBeanDefinition());
        }
        builder.addPropertyValue("urlHandlerMapper", urlHandlerMapperDefinition);
    }

    private List<BeanMetadataElement> parseList(String handlers){
        List<BeanMetadataElement> definitionList = new ManagedList<BeanMetadataElement>();
        String[] handlerArray = handlers.split(",");
        for (String handler : handlerArray){
            // this handler is inject with @Component
            definitionList.add(new RuntimeBeanReference(handler));
        }
        return definitionList;
    }
}
```

but when I run it,throws:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'defaultBeforeHandler' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:680)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1183)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:284)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:275)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
```

this is the `defaultBeforeHandler`

```
@Component
public class DefaultBeforeHandler extends BaseController implements BeforeHandler {
    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DefaultBeforeHandler.class);
    @Override
    public void execute(RouteRequest routeRequest, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception{
        logger.debug("defaultBeforeHandler");
    }
}
```

but when I define defaultBeforeHandler in xml,it will be ok.
how can I use the @Component annotation in my xml parser?

I have already config `<context:component-scan base-package="com.my.app" />` in `applicationContext.xml`

spring version: 4.3

Comment: It may be I don't understand your use case, but why write a "custom XML schema parser"? If your goal is to actually create a web app to respond to requests at your defined URL, using Springs \@Controller, \@RequestMapping annotation may make more sense. The DefaultBeforeHandler could also be a Spring Interceptor. Of course, I'm not actually sure what you're building.

Comment: We have many systems, this `route XML schema parser` is a transfer subject, transfer http requires to other systems behind it

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable component scanning through configuration. Either by annotation or XML. E.g.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.acme.app.services") 
public class AppConfig {
 // various @Bean definitions ... }
```

That example will enable annotation configuration and scan the packages under com.acme.app.services for any annotated classes and register them as beans. Update that string to match the package with your annotated class in it.

See [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html%20docs) for more detail.

Comment: I have already config `<context:component-scan base-package="com.my.app" />` in `applicationContext.xml`